# popup after clicking the html form submit using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

I have a submit button"Certificate copy" when i clicked the button it should show a popup. 
The below one is my html code.

```
print "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>";
print "<form action='details.php' name='copy' method='POST' target='_blank'>";


        print "<input type='hidden' name='certificate_name' value='$certificate_name'>";
        print "<input type='hidden' name='certificate_id' value='$certificate_id'>";


        print "<input type='submit' name='certificatecopy' id='certificate' value='Certificate Copy'>";

print "</form>" ;
```

and my code for popup is

```
    print "<script> $(document).on('click','#certificate',function(){val = confirm('Do you want to create a new certificate?');
alert(val);
if(val)
{
     alert('proceed '); 
     return true;
}
else
{
   alert('Dont proceed');
   return false;
}
});</script>";
```

My problem is, when i click the button at first time the popup box doesn't appear. but when the button clicked second time, the popup box is appear. what is the problem. I need the popup when the button clicked first time. please help.

Comment: Because `if(isset($_POST['certificatecopy'])){..}` not set on First time page load . it will only set  after you click the button

Comment: You want to do this client side - using a click event handler on the button.

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that you are using sessions for this task. I would guess that you set the content of the session after you try to display it, hence when the page loads the second time it works (guessing).

Comment: You need to show your full code. This code will not popup alert

Comment: if any other way is there instead of isset($_POST['certificatecopy']

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in client side on button click event .

Confirm will return the Boolean value true or false . Based on user click.

```js
$(document).on('click','#certificate',function(){

val = confirm('This will create a new certificate with all properties and links from the original certificate. A certificate user may edit the new certificate properties, but may not delete the certificate. Do you want to create a new certificate?');

alert(val);

if(val)
{
     alert('proceed '); 
     return true;
}
else
{
   alert('Dont proceed');
   return false;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='details.php' name='copy' method='POST' target='_blank'>

 <input type='hidden' name='certificate_name' value='$certificate_name'>
  
  <input type='hidden' name='certificate_id' value='$certificate_id'>


<input type='submit' name='certificatecopy' id="certificate" value='Certificate Copy'>
</form>
```

**Update 1 :**

```
<?php
print "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>";
print "<form action='details.php' name='copy' method='POST' target='_blank'>";


        print "<input type='hidden' name='certificate_name' value='$certificate_name'>";
        print "<input type='hidden' name='certificate_id' value='$certificate_id'>";


        print "<input type='submit' name='certificatecopy' id='certificate' value='Certificate Copy'>";

print "</form>" ;

print "<script> $(document).on('click','#certificate',function(){val = confirm('Do you want to create a new certificate?');
alert(val);
if(val)
{
     alert('proceed '); 
     return true;
}
else
{
   alert('Dont proceed');
   return false;
}
});</script>";

?>
```

Comment: The above sample is for alert message. I have to create confirm box.

Comment: No, this is confirm box @SoundaryaE Take a look on my js code .

Comment: Try the above snippet . click the button `Run code Snippet` @SoundaryaE

Comment: Ya it is working. but in my application the popup is not coming

Comment: Can your post with updated code using edit button @SoundaryaE

Comment: you forgot to add id attribute in input `print "<input type='submit' name='certificatecopy'  id="certificate" value='Certificate Copy'>";`  and why your using undefined variable `Copy` instead of that use valid variable `val` @SoundaryaE

Comment: I have changed the code again popup is not coming. whether it may be a problem print "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>";

Comment: Both html and js code are in same page or different page ? @SoundaryaE

Comment: Html is in different page

Comment: Both should be same page as like my updat1 @SoundaryaE

Comment: But i can't do it in same page.

Comment: First of i written code is js it's run in client side .i mean it will run in client browser . so when user click that button while porgram will execute in client broswer and showing the pop alert . based on that user click it will retun true or false . @SoundaryaE

Comment: included file having the html code. I can't merge. This will affect the entire application.

Comment: javascript will not affect any of your code unless you write it in wrong way. @SoundaryaE

Comment: isset($_POST['certificatecopy'] if this will set at first time then my problem got solved. anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding in `$_SESSION['pop_up']` just `echo` it:

```
if(isset($_POST['certificatecopy'])){

  echo "<script>
            .....................
            .....................
        </script>";
```

Comment: I need the popup box because once they click confirm i will excute another function

Comment: JyoThl solution should work

<!-- Your html code -->
  <input type='hidden' name='certificate_id' id='certificate_id' value='$certificate_id'>

  
  
  <script>
  
  $("#certificate_id").click(){
  
   val = confirm('This will create a......');
   
// If any one confirm then only it goes to below condition and call other function as you required

 if(val){
 
  abc()
  
 }
 
  }
  
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

You want to ask for the confirmation Client side before sending a request to the server?

If you use Bootstrap, you can try a little jQuery plugin I made, https://github.com/delboy1978uk/bs-delete-confirm. It doesn't need to be used solely for deletion, it's only named that since it's the most used case.

All you do is add a CSS class to your link:

```
<a href="/wherever" class="confirm">Do stuff!</a>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.confirm').deleteConfirm();
});
```

Now when you click the link, the JS intercepts it, launches a bootstrap modal window, and upon confirming, follows your hyperlink.

You can pass options in to the deleteConfirm() method too:

```
{
  heading: "Please confirm",
  body: "Are you sure you wish to perform this action?",
  ok_text: "Proceed",
  cancel_text: "Back",
  log: false
}
```

Hope this helps! If you don't use Bootstrap, it's well worth addingto your project! Here's a link to the modal functionality:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

Comment: I am new to this. If i add ajax in my code, then anything additionally add to my php code like libraries